# Trying to pass variables as arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to do an assignment and I cannot for the life of me figure this out. This is the following directions: write a calculator program that can calculate the greatest preceding integer and the least succeeding integer of a user-entered float number. This program should have two functions: main function and calculate function.
I know this is very basic, but I am just getting started in my learning. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import math

def calculate(num):
    result = math.floor(num)
    result2 = math.ceil(num)
    return result, result2


def main():
    number = float(input('Enter a float number: '))
    res = calculate(number)
    print('The floor is',,'and the ceil is',)

main()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When the print function executes how do I pass the variables in "calculate function definition" down? The print function should read The floor is (result) and the ceil is (result2)

Comment: A function returning multiple values returns them as a tuple. So basically you have `res = (result, result2)`. Does this give you a clue how to cotinue?

Comment: `calculate` returns a tuple `(result, result2)`, so in `res = calculate(number)`, `res` is the tuple. Now you just need to extract the two elements of that tuple

Comment: You have an extra ``enter code here`` in your code, you shoud remove that.
This line might help, `print('The floor is {} and the ceil is {}'.format(*res))`(documentation for `format` here: [https://pyformat.info/](https://pyformat.info/) and the `*` is the "unpack" operator for lists

Comment: Alternatively, you can already unpack the function call: `floor, ceil = calculate(number)`

Comment: Thank you all so much, it helped me greatly. Sorry for the basic question, this is my first time doing any type of programming.

Comment: It is better (for your own learning experience) to try and find some documentations before rushing to ask here. Thankfully, Python has amazing and detailed documentations so you just need to know what to search for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `calculate()` returns two values. There are two ways to deal with this:

1. Catch both returns in separate variables and use them:

   ```
   res1, res2 = calculate(0.5)
   ```
2. Catch both returns in a single variable (a tuple), which you can then unpack:

   ```
   res = calculate(0.5)
   res1 = res[0]
   res2 = res[1]
   ```

So your complete code for the first case could then look like:

```
import math

def calculate(num):
    result = math.floor(num)
    result2 = math.ceil(num)
    return result, result2

def main():
    number = float(input('Enter a float number: '))
    res1, res2 = calculate(number)
    print('The floor is', res1, 'and the ceil is', res2)

main()
```